# Parse JSON Swift 3 Dictionary

Tags: json, swift, parsing, dictionary, swift3

I am attempting to try to get all 31 teams from the NHL from this JSON link. Here is a look at what the file looks like:

```
{
   "sports":[
      {
         "name":"hockey",
         "slug":"hockey",
         "id":70,
         "uid":"s:70",
         "leagues":[
            {
               "name":"National Hockey League",
               "slug":"nhl",
               "abbreviation":"nhl",
               "id":90,
               "uid":"s:70~l:90",
               "groupId":9,
               "shortName":"NHL",
               "teams":[
                  {
                      ...team info....
                  }......
```

I currently have this do statement in function trying to loop thru all 31 entries in the "teams" array:

```
if let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {
     if let entries: NSArray = parsedData["sports"] as! NSArray  {
        for entry in entries {
            //work with data
        }
     }
}
```

I know I have to dig a bit deeper on the "if let entries" line, but I can't seem to get the data I want. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: `parsedData["sports"]` is an array, not a dictionary.

Comment: I just changed my code a bit. Got the entries line to work, but I can't go deeper into that to get to the "leagues" array within the "sports" array

Comment: Do not use `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` with Swift.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, why do so many tutorials suggest / people use `.mutableContainers` although the object is never going to be mutated and ironically the result is mostly assigned to an **im**mutable object?

**Don't do that**. Pass *no options* by omitting the parameter.

Second of all don't fight Swift's strong type system. Use native collection types `Array` and `Dictionary` and do not annotate types the compiler can infer.

Let`s create a type alias for convenience:

```
typealias JSONDictionary = [String:Any]

if let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? JSONDictionary,
```

The value for key `sports` is an array (represented by `[]`)

```
   let sports = parsedData["sports"] as? [JSONDictionary] {
```

Enumerate the array and get the value for key `leagues` which is also an array

```
      for sport in sports {
          print("sport ", sport["name"] as? String ?? "n/a")
          if let leagues = sport["leagues"] as? [JSONDictionary] {
```

Do the same with `leagues` and get the `teams`

```
             for league in leagues {
                print("league ", league["name"] as? String ?? "n/a")
                if let teams = league["teams"] as? [JSONDictionary] {
                for team in teams {
```

Parsing JSON is pretty easy, there are only two collection types and four value types.

```
                }  
             }
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: @CalebRudnicki if that solved your question mark the answer as correct